# Weblogic : Spring application context loading fails : Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an MDB which listens on a JMS Queue, In the onMessage() i need to call a spring bean for which i am using SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.

As i post message into the JMS Queue, the MDB is actually trying to load the spring application context but fails with the following error.

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: 
Unable to     initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], 
factory key [null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'parentBeanFactory' defined in URL 
[zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/factoryadaptor-1.0.0-api/4f4fxo/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'localEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path      resource [beans/applicationContext-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

The excerpt of Applicationcontext-db.xml

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager" />

 <bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="localEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>



<bean id="localEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DMS" />    
     <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:config/persistence1.xml" />
</bean> 

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="localEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

The excerpt of pom.xml is as below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

As i see in the eclipse dependency hierarchy for hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar includes hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.jar.

The same configuration works well when tried as Junit for intercating with DB. As i deploy the war in weblogic 12c, i am facing the above mentioned issue.

Did anyone face the similar issue?

Comment: Do you have `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.jar` in Weblogic classpath ? Looks like weblogic 12c uses an old JPA API by default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Artem Bilan. As i have hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final jar as a dependency, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.jar is added as dependency as shown in eclipse dependency hierarchy. Also i checked the WEB-INF/lib directory with in the war and it has hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.jar in it.

Comment: I was temporarily able to resolve this application context loading issue by replacing the hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final with hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by providing the following in weblogic.xml telling weblogic you want to use provided hibernate (including jpa):

```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javassist</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this option in weblogic.xml
`<wls:container-descriptor>
<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>

</wls:container-descriptor>`